# If $A, B$, and $C$ are events such that $A \subset B \subset C$, what are the probabilities of $A\cup B \cup C$ and $A \cap B \cap C$?

Tags: probability-theory

I know that if $B\subset A$, then $A \cup B = A $ and $A \cap B = B$. So if $A \subset B \subset C$, would $A\cup B \cup C = C$ and $A \cap B \cap C = A$? What if $C \subset B \subset A$, would $A \cup B \cup C = A$ and $A \cap B \cap C = C$?

Comment: Yes, just apply "what you know" for twice.

Comment: Assuming $A, B$, and $C$ are events such that $A \subset B \subset C$, we have $P(A\cup B \cup C)=P(C)$ and $P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A)$. But you should take the time to write out the steps to convince yourself by using the fact that $P(E\cup F)=P(E)+P(F)-P(E\cap F)$ for any two events $E$ and $F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\cup B\cup C\supset C$ (trivial).

$x\in A\cup B\cup C\Rightarrow x\in A\space\text{or}\space x\in B\space\text{or}\space x\in C$. But $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B\Rightarrow x\in C\dots$(i) for every $x\in A$, $x\in B\Rightarrow x\in C\dots$(ii) for every $x\in B$. Now suppose $x\in A\cup B\cup C$ but $x\notin C$, then we must have $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ which violates (i), (ii). Then $A\cup B\cup C\subset C$.

Alternative:

$A\cup B\cup C=(C\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)\cup A=C$(Disjoint union)

Similar way you can show $A\cap B\cap C=A$